# How do I reverse the DLL hack done by UxTheme Patch?

Tags: windows-7, dll

I have downloaded the ova file for Sagemath 6.6, the problem is that VirtualBox gives me this error, whenever I attempt to start the Sage virtual machine:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Sage-6.6.

Unable to load R3 module C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxDD.DLL (VBoxDD): GetLastError=1790 (VERR_UNRESOLVED_ERROR).

Result Code:    E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:  Console
Interface:  IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

I have installed UxTheme patcher (from http://www.syssel.net/hoefs/software_uxtheme.php?lang=en) and as I understand it the DLL hacks associated with it might be causing the issue. The problem is that now I do not know how to uninstall this program (no icon for the program appears in Control panel/Revo uninstaller/CCleaner when I try to uninstall it). This is the problem I need help with.

EDIT: I have tried reinstalling the software, but I still can't find the software's icon in any of the above mentioned uninstaller software. The installer doesn't (or at least it doesn't for me) come with an uninstall option.

Comment: Yeah, and how do I do that reversal?

Comment: Read my question, I have edited it to answer your question.

Comment: OK, so what do you suggest I do after changing my question? The downvote told me that I must be asking the wrong question, so I edited the question into what I was assuming it should be. If you have any constructive criticism or advice I'd like to hear it.

Comment: How do I roll it back to the restoration point?

Comment: @Ramhound if you look at the revision history, he didn't completely change the question, he edited it to more clearly address the issue at hand. Editing a question to improve it is a valid and encouraged response to critical comments and downvotes. This seems quite reasonable to me, and notifying a user who is engaged in a comments conversation about a question that the question has been edited seems quite reasonable as well.

Comment: @nhinkle - While I disagree the question didn't completely change, I am willing to just walk away, since the question was improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to undo modifications to Windows system files like uxtheme.dll, you can run the [System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) which is built in to Windows.

Open an elevated command prompt by typing "cmd" into the start menu and pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter when `cmd.exe` is highlighted.

Type `sfc /scannow`. The system file checker will run, and replace any modified system files with the original version. When finished running the file checker will report whether any files were modified. You should be able to check the logfile it produces to see if uxtheme.dll was replaced.